# Select the next div

Tags: jquery

i want to show the next div when i select the input like the following, how can i do that ..

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="domain">Do you have a <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+domain+&oq=what+is+domain+&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i65j69i60l2j0l2.2204j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8">domain</a> ? </label>
            <div class="controls" name="domain">
                <select id="select">
                    <option value="0">Pick one</option>
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="2">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- the name of the domain -->

        <div class="control-group" style="display:none">
            <label class="control-label" for="domain_name">Domain name ? </label>
            <div class="controls" name="domain_name">
                {{ Form::text('domain_name', null, array('required')) }}
                <p class="help-block"><b>http://domain.com</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery i used

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // show the inputs that is hidden 
 $('#select').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == '1')
    {
        $(this).parent('.control-group').next('.control-group').show();
    }
 })
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) here

```
$(this).closest('.control-group').next('.control-group').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not:

```
$(this).parent('.control-group').next('.control-group').show();
```

but:

```
$(this).parent(".controls").parent('.control-group').next('.control-group').show();
```

That should help

**Edit:** Answer of Arun P Johny is the best one I think :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().next(".control-group").show();
```

Hope this help